# How to pair AWS EC2 MacOS Instance to Visual Studio

Tags: amazon-web-services, macos, visual-studio, amazon-ec2, ssh

I am currently developing a mobile app for iOS and Android using .NET MAUI. I am running Visual Studio 2022 Preview on Windows 10 (Visual Studio Version 17.3.0), so to debug and run an emulator for iOS I need to pair Visual Studio to a Mac (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/ios/pair-to-mac).

I have an AWS MacOS EC2 Instance on a dedicated host for this (running Monterey 12.4). From my local machine, I can ssh into it using the ".pem" file I received from AWS. I have followed all the relevant instructions to enable remote login on the Mac, and I established a VNC connection so I could verify all the settings in the GUI. I set up a password for the ec2-user profile because Visual Studio requires a username and password to pair to the Mac instead of ssh keys. Every time I try to connect with Visual Studio, I receive an error stating I have incorrect credentials. I have tried:

1. Changing ssh settings in /etc/ssh/sshd_config. I have set PasswordAuthentication = yes and PermitRootLogin = yes. I have tried setting ChallengeResponseAuthentication = yes or no at different times and have done the same thing for the UsePAM setting. Whenever I have changed settings I've restarted the sshd service using:

```
sudo launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist
sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist
```

2. I have edited the /usr/local/aws/ec2-macos-init/init.toml file to allow password authentication and stop the ec2-user password from being randomized. I don't think this should affect me much though, as this config file (I believe) is only run when the machine is rebooted.

In both of the above attempts, I cannot connect to my instance with Visual Studio, and when I try to connect over ssh without the key file, I receive the error:

`Permission Denied (Public Key)`

3. I added ssh keys to the remote server and my local .ssh directory so I can login without specifying the .pem file. I hoped perhaps I could then connect in Visual Studio without a password. I can connect fine from ssh, but still cannot connect with Visual Studio.

None of this has worked. Any suggestions for how to connect to this MacOS EC2 instance with a password instead of a key would be much appreciated. I presume if that works I will be able to connect with Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

You need

1. Edit file /usr/local/aws/ec2-macos-init/init.toml

   secureSSHDConfig = false
2. Edit /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/050-ec2-macos.conf

   PasswordAuthentication yes
   ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes
   UsePAM yes
3. Reboot macos